# Getting "Index was outside the bounds of the array" exception

Tags: c#, arrays, string, exception, stream

we have a datatable "st" with two columns "word" and "binary"

```
void replace()
    {

        string s1="", s2="";            
        StreamReader streamReader;
        streamReader = File.OpenText("C:\\text.txt");
        StreamWriter streamWriter = File.CreateText("C:\\sample1.txt");
        int x = st.Rows.Count;
       // int i1 = 0;                                       
            // Now, read the entire file into a string
            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
                {

                s1 = Convert.ToString(st.Rows[i]["Word"]);
                s2 = Convert.ToString(st.Rows[i]["Binary"]);
                s2+="000";
                char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', '\t' };
                String[] words = line.Split(delimiterChars);

                    // Write the modification into the same file                    
                String ab = words[i]; //exception occurs here
                // Console.WriteLine(ab);
                streamWriter.Write(ab.Replace(s1,s2));                                 
                }                
            }
        streamReader.Close();
        streamWriter.Close();
    }
```

we're getting an "Index was outside the bounds of the array" exception. we're unable to find the problem. thanks in advance

EDIT:
tnx to everyone who helped.
i did this and it worked somehow:

```
 void replace()
    {
        string s1 = "", s2 = "";
        StreamReader streamReader;
        streamReader = File.OpenText("C:\\sample1.txt");
        StreamWriter streamWriter = File.CreateText("C:\\sample1.txt");
        int x = st.Rows.Count;           
        while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', '\t' };
            String[] words = line.Split(delimiterChars);
            foreach (string str in words)
            {

                s1 = str;
                DataRow drow = st.Rows.Find(str);
                if (drow != null)
                {
                    index = st.Rows.IndexOf(drow);
                    s2 = Convert.ToString(st.Rows[index]["Binary"]);
                  // s2 += "000";
                    // ab = words[i];                        
                    Console.WriteLine(s1);
                    Console.WriteLine(s2);
                    streamWriter.Write(str.Replace(s1, s2));                                 
                }
                else
                    break;
            }               
        }
        streamReader.Close();
        streamWriter.Close();
    }
```

tnx to everyone once again.
regards,
sagar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a hypothetical line "a b c d e" for instance the first line in your file, and your database "st" contains 10 rows, you would loop through the process 10 times, on the 6th time you would encounter the error. The 6th step would split the string into: {a, b, c, d, e} and then attempt to get the 5th index (zero based), which would be outside of the array.

Comment: so how can i avoid it? plz help

Comment: @vidya if I understand your application from the sample you are looking for words to replace in a string, and then putting the modified string back in the file. First I would hoist all of the steps outside of the inner loop that you can, splitting the string and the delimiter characters can be done outside the for loop. Then within the for loop you actually want to look at each word in the split string to be replaced. One method of doing this is to add a for loop that iterates over each split word. An easier and more straightforward method would be to use the List<string> and extension methods

Answer (score 5):

The way you are basing off i is the number of row count aka X and not the length of the string array. Therefore you might have 100 rows but the string is split into only 5 string values.

Answer (score 2):

`i` is the index of the line you are on.

```
while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)  // say we are on line 20
```

`words` contains an array of the words on that line.

```
String[] words = line.Split(delimiterChars); // say there are 3 words on line 20
```

If there are less words in the line than the line index... you get an out of bounds exception.

```
String ab = words[i]; // trying to get to word 20 out of 3...
```

---

You need to use a valid index value for the number of words in that line - it is not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve in your code, so I can't provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the debugger, in order to look what is in `line` and in the `words` array and compare it to the value of `i`. The debugger is your best friend.